# Looking for an unobtrusive "Email a friend" form

Tags: javascript, forms, email, sharing

Does anyone know if a good "email a friend" form that doesn't require loads of javascript and tracking cookies?

[AddThis](http://www.addthis.com/tellfriend.php) seems to be very close to what I'm looking for, but even for a simple 'email a friend' link, you have to load their API.

At this point, I am considering triggering a plain-old `mailto:` link that's preloaded with the url and page title.

```
<a href="mailto:someone@somewhere.com?subject=&body=">Lame</a>
```

There must be something better than this???

Comment: What more would you need than that?

Comment: Well, using a mailto has many limitations including limited control over the message body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided stick with the basic mailto: link for now, but based on my findings (or lack thereof), I probably would have coded my own form to avoid all of the baggage that comes with using a third-party plugin such as AddThis.